# It is possible to use FAPI #states on hidden elements?

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to enable a submit button based of a hidden input value. Right now i have this but it does not seem to work.

```
$states = array();
        $dependencies = array();
        foreach ($w_exercise->get($field_question_name) as $question){
            dpm('input_value-'.$question_bundle.'-'.$question->id->value());
            $dependencies[':input[name="input_value-'.$question_bundle.'-'.$question->id->value().'"]'] = array(
                '!value' => '0',
            );
        }
        $states['enabled'] = $dependencies;
        $form['exercise-footer']['exercise-footer-container']['op']['check'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Check'),
            '#validate' => array($validate_function),
            '#executes_submit_callback' => false,
            '#states' => $states,
        );
```

Comment: The inputs name are correct

Comment: If you are talking of the _hidden_ form API element, then no, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes it was for the hidden form API element, thank you for the response.

Comment: Also, you are using `!value`. I assume you meant `'value' => '0'`.

Comment: I wanted it when all of the hidden inputs (there are a few) have a value different from 0, im changing its values with a js attached to the form. I have used !value in textfield, radios form api elements and it seems to work. My final idea is to enable the submit button when all of respectives form api element have changed its default value gave it to them on load